bulding docker image for an arm32v7 processor
I managed to build a working docker image on my development laptop, but got an  exec format error when I tried to run the docker image on the PC that the container shall run on.
My dev PC is an ubuntu 24 with an intel i7 processor. The PC that I want to run the container on is a Linux PREEMT_RT OS with an Cortex A8 processor (arm32v7).
I changed the dockerfile from
FROM alpine as build-env to FROM arm32v7/alpine as build-env, but that gives me an error on the RUN apk add --no cache build-base line.
I guess my problem is how to compile the .C-file in an arm32v7 environment. When I try to build the docker image below I get the error:
 => ERROR [build-env 2/5] RUN apk add gcc musl-dev                         1.7s
------                                                                          
 > [build-env 2/5] RUN apk add gcc musl-dev:
1.525 exec /bin/sh: exec format error

I appreciate every answer, I'm pretty stuck on this one. Thanks in advance!
# use alpine as base image
FROM arm32v7/alpine as build-env
# install build-base meta package inside build-env container
RUN apk add --no-cache build-base
# change directory to /app
WORKDIR /app
# copy all files from current directory inside the build-env container
COPY . .
# Compile the source code and generate hello binary executable file
RUN gcc -std=c99 myclient.c -lm -o opc_client
# use another container to run the program
FROM arm32v7/alpine
# copy binary executable to new container
COPY --from=build-env /app/opc_client /app/opc_client

WORKDIR /app
# at last run the program
CMD ["/app/opc_client"] 

